# What are these types of coin cell contacts called?

Tags: batteries, pcb, identification, coin-cell

I am working on a low-profile product that will be powered by a coin cell. I've seen some products that use coin cell contacts that allow the battery to be *beside* the PCB, rather than on top of it. This saves Z height, and is desirable for my application. Note that these contacts are installed onto the PCB, not built into the coin cell itself. This means that the battery is easily replaceable.

I've spent several hours looking for parts like this, but all of the battery clips I've been able to find are in a style where the battery's height is on top of the PCB's height, rather than next to it. What is the correct name for this style of battery clip?

Example photos below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://eu.mouser.com/c/?q=battery%20holder%20cr2032

Comment: @G36 yep, I'm aware that generic CR2032 holders are readily available. I'm specifically looking for styles that do NOT require the height of the PCB to be added to the height of the battery. The vast majority of holders on Mouser/Digikey require the coin cell to be stacked on top of FR4.

Comment: Well, primarily they are called cheap :) These are typically custom- or semi-custom ordered parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would go under a name such as "Ultra Low Profile" coin battery holder.  Here is a similar part from Keystone that also requires a cut out in the PCB.
https://www.keystone-europe.com/tag/coin-cell-holders/   Another drawing with dimensions: https://ken.keyeuro.eu/pdf/1057TR.pdf

Comment: As single piece components these could also be called coin cell smt contacts, clips, or springs. How you mount them, the PCB cut out, and how it works with the outer enclosure is up to the designer.  Here are some additional examples offered from Alibaba.  https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/3v-THM-DIP-SMT-Metal-Button_62060174864.html

Answer (score 1):

Given  a CR2032 with the cathode recessed below the top side requires a hole to permit  1 pc or 2 pc contacts for anode and cathode.

This cathode holder would cost more than the item with less mat'l in your photo, in high volume, but satisfies your height requirements.

However knowing that MOQ's are often $300, you need to order sufficient quantity.

[image]
https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/346/SMTM2032-258029.pdf

If you needed to offset the centre towards the top side, some spacers soldered to top side pads would complicate the assembly.

### another cathode holder

https://www.batteryholders.com/part.php?pn=BC-2003&original=CR2032&override=CR2032

### Recommendaton

Designs must learn to specify must have measurable specs and nice to have specs.